# checking if browser is FF < 3.6.14

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I know that in general, we want to check for the presence of specific properties that a browser will have, rather than digging into the user agent string, but I have a special circumstance where I need to do something if the user is running a version of Firefox < 3.6.14.

I'm looking at window.navigator.userAgent, which seems to have everything I need, but any hints or gotchas I might not think of?

Comment: [User Agent can be spoofed.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)

Comment: I know. It's an imperfect situation.

Comment: So what *is* it that you want to check?

Comment: Whenever I see questions like this, my first thought is: Why do you need to target specific [versions](http://www.mozilla.org/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox36.html#firefox3.6.14)?

Comment: I can't go into all the details, but there's a minor bug that just got patched in 3.6.14 that I was taking advantage of in a complex situation. (For good, not evil.) I can't think of another way to test whether the bug is present, given the nature of the bug. So I need to test the user agent and take the lack of the bug into account.

Comment: Whatever you're doing, I'm fairly sure you've made the wrong choice.

Comment: @sprugman: Please do go into the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [list of Firefox user agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Firefox/). There are some surprises like `3.6.1pre` and `Firefox 3.6b5` that you will need to be able to match. Using a library may indeed be the best idea, if the library manages to interpret these numbers correctly.

Answer (score 1):

While you almost never want to parse the userAgent, I'll assume you're operating against one of those rare weird cases where you do. Parsing userAgents is like one big gotcha, so you're probably best off using an existing library.

This code at quirksmode is probably a good starting point: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html. It should give you the major and minor version (3.6), so you will need to modify it if you need the .14.

Comment: thanks for the link. Since my case is so specific, I wound up writing my own.

Answer (score -1):

You're better off testing the JavaScript functions you want to use rather than the version of the browser.  This tells you what you need to know and you don't need to worry what browser or version you have - you know the functions will or won't work.

Comment: see the first phrase of my question.

Comment: Perhaps I read to quickly.  To be fair, I would have given the same answer up until your long comment above mentioning the bug that you're trying to detect.